# Switch display manager to lightdm

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, display, arm

I  downloaded `lightdm` for my ubuntu 18 (aarch64), installed it and set it as default.
When I type

```
   cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

this is the output

```
    /usr/sbin/lightdm
```

But desktop is still gdm3 even if I restart pc. Why?[image]

Answer (score 4):

lightdm and gdm3 are "Displaymanagers" not "Desktop environments".

Unless you install another Desktop Environement like KDE or i3, neither of the two Displaymanagers can offer you any choice and will send you to the one Desktop Environment you have available: Gnome.